# Does "for all the" mean a contrast or a cause and effect or a irony?

Tags: phrases, irony

Does "for all the" mean a contrast or a cause and effect?

"For all the work he put in, the project was sure a disaster. "

Does this mean because of all the work he put in, the project was bad?
May you infer if he the project was good, then he didn't work hard?

Comment: Both. It's adversative, meaning  'in spite of' -- there was (a lot of) work put in to bring about a result, but the project was not a success even with all that work.

Answer (score 2):

[MW defines "for all"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20all) as "in spite of." So the primary effect is to draw a contrast; one might expect that his work would have led to success, but in fact he nevertheless failed.